# Spring-data-jpa same table name on two datasources "Duplicate entity name"

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring-data-jpa with two datasources, 
but my two schema elettroforesi and capillare both have a table ANALISI

and Eclipse show me the following error:

```
"Duplicate entity name "Analisi" found in the persistence unit. Entity names must be unique."
```

the Config are the following:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-multiple-db.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.repository.elettroforesi", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "elettroforesiEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "elettroforesiTransactionManager")
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.interlabsrl.elfolab.controller",
        "com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.service", 
        "com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.cache"})
public class ElettroforesiConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public ElettroforesiConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean elettroforesiEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("elettroforesi");
        em.setDataSource(elettroforesiDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.model.elettroforesi" });
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", env.getProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource elettroforesiDataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("elettroforesi.jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("elettroforesi.jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("elettroforesi.jdbc.pass")));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public PlatformTransactionManager elettroforesiTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(elettroforesiEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

and

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({ "classpath:persistence-multiple-db.properties" })
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
        basePackages = "com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.repository.capillare", 
        entityManagerFactoryRef = "capillareEntityManager", 
        transactionManagerRef = "capillareTransactionManager")
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.interlabsrl.elfolab.controller",
//      , "com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.service" 
//      "com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.cache"
        })
public class CapillareConfig {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public CapillareConfig() {
        super();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean capillareEntityManager() {
        final LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setPersistenceUnitName("capillare");
        em.setDataSource(capillareDataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] { "com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.model.capillare" });
        final HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        final HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", env.getProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size", env.getProperty("hibernate.jdbc.batch_size"));
        em.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);
        return em;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource capillareDataSource() {
        final DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("jdbc.driverClassName")));
        dataSource.setUrl(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("capillare.jdbc.url")));
        dataSource.setUsername(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("capillare.jdbc.user")));
        dataSource.setPassword(Preconditions.checkNotNull(env.getProperty("capillare.jdbc.pass")));
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager capillareTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(capillareEntityManager().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

while the entities:

```
package com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.model.elettroforesi;

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Analisi.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Analisi a")})
@Table(schema="elettroforesi")
public class Analisi implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "ID_ANALISI", nullable = false)
    private Integer idAnalisi;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private short tracciato;
    @Size(max = 30)
    @Column(length = 30)
    private String campione;
    @Size(max = 40)
    @Column(length = 40)
    private String reparto;
    @Column(name = "TOTALE_PROTEINE", precision = 12)
    private Float totaleProteine;
    @Column(name = "RAPP_AG", precision = 12)
    private Float rappAg;
    @Column(name = "DATA_MODIFICA")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataModifica;
    @Column(name = "DATA_VALIDAZIONE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataValidazione;
    @Column(name = "DATA_CANCELLAZIONE")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataCancellazione;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idAnalisiLink")
    private Collection<Analisi> analisiCollection;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ANALISI_LINK", referencedColumnName = "ID_ANALISI")
    @ManyToOne
    private Analisi idAnalisiLink;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ANALISI_IFE", referencedColumnName = "ID_ANALISI_IFE")
    @ManyToOne
    private AnalisiIfe idAnalisiIfe;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_ANALISI_NOTA", referencedColumnName = "ID_ANALISI_NOTA")
    @ManyToOne
    private AnalisiNota idAnalisiNota;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PATOLOGICO", referencedColumnName = "ID_PATOLOGICO")
    @ManyToOne
    private Patologico idPatologico;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_PAZIENTE", referencedColumnName = "ID_PAZIENTE", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Paziente idPaziente;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_SESSIONE", referencedColumnName = "ID_SESSIONE", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private Sessione idSessione;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE", referencedColumnName = "ID_TIPO_VALIDAZIONE", nullable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    private TipoValidazione idTipoValidazione;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_UTENTE_CANCELLAZIONE", referencedColumnName = "ID_UTENTE")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Utente idUtenteCancellazione;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_UTENTE_MODIFICA", referencedColumnName = "ID_UTENTE")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Utente idUtenteModifica;
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID_UTENTE_VALIDAZIONE", referencedColumnName = "ID_UTENTE")
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Utente idUtenteValidazione;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idAnalisi", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<AnalisiFrazione> analisiFrazioneCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idAnalisi", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<AnalisiAntisiero> analisiAntisieroCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idAnalisi", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<AnalisiSmc> analisiSmcCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idAnalisi", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<AnalisiCampoFree> analisiCampoFreeCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idAnalisi", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<AnalisiDati>     analisiDatiCollection;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "idAnalisi")
    private Collection<AnalisiNefelometrico> analisiNefelometricoCollection;    

...

}
```

and

```
package com.interlabsrl.elfolab.persistence.multiple.model.capillare;

...

@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Analisi.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Analisi a")})
@Table(schema="capillare")
public class Analisi implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "id_macchina")
    private Integer idMacchina;
    @Column(name = "id_metodiche")
    private Integer idMetodiche;
    @Column(name = "numero_sessione")
    private Integer numeroSessione;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataora;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date data;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "barcode_provetta", length = 20)
    private String barcodeProvetta;
    @Size(max = 20)
    @Column(name = "barcode_rack", length = 20)
    private String barcodeRack;
    @Size(max = 100)
    @Column(name = "dati_lettura", length = 100)
    private String datiLettura;
    private Short acquisito;

    ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your entities are both named Analisi, try to change the second one to Capillare.
You named the table Capillare, but the class is named Analisi

Comment: Table is Analisi, the schema is Capillare, it seems strange to me that I've to pay attention to use different entity or table name also if I'm using different schemas

Comment: For me the error is pretty clear: Entity names must be unique. So maybe you can try to name the two entities differently. For example you can name the first entity class ElettroforesiAnalisi and the second one CapillareAnalisi. As far as i know the important thing to spring to find the table in your db is the @Table annotation with the correct table name (and schema in your case) not the class name. So specify the table name in the annotation.Then you have to change your named query like this `SELECT a FROM CapillareAnalisi a`. Let me know if it works

Comment: You're welcome! Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers, and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask.